# Access javascript <td table data without id, with swift3

Tags: javascript, html, swift3

inspecting target website shows the following HTML for a table
(excerpt from full table body)

```
<tr class="simRowA">
    <td class="1stColumn">something</td>
    <td class="2ndColumn">TARGET</td>
    <td class="3rdColumn">anything</td>
    <td class="4thColumn">whatever</td>
</tr>
<tr class="simRowB">
    <td class="1stColumn">something2</td>
    <td class="2ndColumn">TARGET2</td>
    <td class="3rdColumn">anything2</td>
    <td class="4thColumn">whatever2</td>
</tr>
<tr class="simRowA">
    <td class="1stColumn">something3</td>
    <td class="2ndColumn">TARGET3</td>
    <td class="3rdColumn">anything3</td>
    <td class="4thColumn">whatever3</td>
</tr>
<tr class="simRowB">
    <td class="1stColumn">something4</td>
    <td class="2ndColumn">TARGET4</td>
    <td class="3rdColumn">anything4</td>
    <td class="4thColumn">whatever4</td>
</tr>
```

---

"simRowA"(/"B") continue to alternate.

I want to extract "TARGET", "TARGET2"...etc in my Swift3 app

---

I've tried in NavigationDidFinish:WKWebView (other evaluatJavaScript codes are working here)

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByClassName('simRowA')[0].innerText;") {
                (result, error) -> Void in
                print(result)
            }
```

as well as ".value" and ".text". note HTML lacks 'id'

Any suggestions how i can extract this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things that might have gone wrong with your code, and, since some of it is missing, I'm gonna make some asumptions.

First, to correctly get to TR simRowA via `getElementsByClass`, you need to properly construct the table. That means, setting the `<table>` tag too.

```
<table>
    <tr class="simRowA">
        <td class="1stColumn">something</td>
        <td class="2ndColumn">TARGET</td>
        <td class="3rdColumn">anything</td>
        <td class="4thColumn">whatever</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="simRowB">
        <td class="1stColumn">something2</td>
        <td class="2ndColumn">TARGET2</td>
        <td class="3rdColumn">anything2</td>
        <td class="4thColumn">whatever2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="simRowA">
        <td class="1stColumn">something3</td>
        <td class="2ndColumn">TARGET3</td>
        <td class="3rdColumn">anything3</td>
        <td class="4thColumn">whatever3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="simRowB">
        <td class="1stColumn">something4</td>
        <td class="2ndColumn">TARGET4</td>
        <td class="3rdColumn">anything4</td>
        <td class="4thColumn">whatever4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Second, make sure you call `stringByEvaluatingJavaScript` (or, if you're using WKWebView, `evaluateJavaScript`) **after** the page is done loading, so use the delegate method `webViewDidFinishLoad` (or, if you're using WKWebView, `didFinishNavigation`).

After this, you should be getting the innerHTML of .simRowA on the console:

```
Optional("<td class=\"1stColumn\">something</td>\n    <td class=\"2ndColumn\">TARGET</td>\n    <td class=\"3rdColumn\">anything</td>\n    <td class=\"4thColumn\">whatever</td>\n")
```

Comment: I've edited to reflect that other evaluateJavaScript code is working, `webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByClassName('simRowA')[0].innerHTML;")` still printed out `nil` as does if i call by class `'2ndColumn')[0].innerHTML`

Comment: i figured out what was wrong, code would run too quick table wasn't populating fast enough after `.click()` prior to my code.  Most efficient was `webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByClassName('2ndColumn')[0].innerHTML;")`  ty